# Is compound if checking for null and then other condition in C always safe?

Tags: c, if-statement, operator-precedence

(this question is an exact copy of [Is compound if checking for null and then other condition in C++ always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776927/is-compound-if-checking-for-null-and-then-other-condition-in-c-always-safe) but **about C**, not C++. It was pointed out that the question should be more specific).

I have been using the following type of `if` condition for a lot of time.

```
char* ptr = ...;
if (ptr != NULL && ptr[0] != '\0') // <=== is this always safe?
{ /* ... */ }
```

It relies on `ptr != NULL` being checked before `ptr[0] !='\0'`.

Is it safe under all standards, compilers, architectures? Or is there a possibility that `ptr[0] != '\0'` will be checked before `ptr != NULL`?

Comment: `&&` has associativity from Left to Right which means the Left expression is evaluated before the right one.

Comment: @SakthiKumar: No, that's not at all what it means. Fortunately both things happen to be true.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one please...

Comment: @SakthiKumar no, associativity does not affect the order of evaluation which is undefined in c++ (although not in the case for &&)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I created a second question about C++, you are right, in C++ the problem is more complex.

Comment: Sidenote: You could simplify that test to `if(ptr && *ptr)`, which may be more readable.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is safe.

C standard says (N1570 - 6.5.13 Logical AND operator):

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.

Comment: +1 for quoting the standard :)

Comment: +½ for quoting _one_ standard only

Comment: Consider moving your C++ answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776927/is-compound-if-checking-for-null-and-then-other-condition-in-c-always-safe

Comment: Maybe also add: "Yes" first.

Answer (score 2):

If ptr is a built in type then this is always safe. The compiler must evaluate the left hand side first and only evaluate the right hand side if the left side is true.

If ptr is a user defined type (which it isn't here) then this may not apply as operator&& can be overridden in the class and it DOES NOT short circuit like this.

Comment: @juanchopanza correct, that's why I said if ptr is a user defined type. That does not apply in the users code. I just wanted to make it clear to anyone reading the answer that your can't in general assume that && is short circuited without looking at the types involved. Feel free to improve the wording in the answer if its wrong or confusing.

Comment: Ah OK, somehow I managed to read "pointer" in there. I will remove my comment.

Comment: It doesn't only require you to overload `&&`, but also `!=`, to result in a type with overloaded `&&`.

Comment: Ok the example here does of course. I just wanted to point out that in general be careful with && though... With a smart pointer don't write " if (sptr && sptr->data())" like you might with a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its safe. It's called short-circuit evaluation and applies to the logical-and and logical-or operators.

In logical-and (**&&**) the right side is only evaluated if the left side is true.

In logical-or (**||**) the right side is only evaluated if the left side is false.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already explain how short circuit evaluation guarantees that the code is safe - however, this only holds for a *single thread*.

If there are multiple threads executing the same code, and `ptr` is not using thread-local-storage, it may well be that in

```
ptr != NULL && ptr[0] != '\0')
```

You have a sequence like:

- Thread 1 verifies that `ptr != NULL` is true.
- Thread 2 assigns `ptr = NULL`
- Thread 1 attempts to access `ptr[0]` and segfaults.

Comment: True, however this only applies if concurrent access to `ptr` is not protected. Such code I'd consider broken anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you write `char* ptr = ...`.

So the answer depends on the context in which you assign `ptr` with a value.

As long as you assign `ptr` either with a valid memory address or with `NULL`, then it should be safe.

But if you assign `ptr` with an invalid memory address which is **not** `NULL`, then your code is unsafe.

For example:

```
char* ptr = func();

char* func()
{
    char* str; // possibly pointing to an invalid memory address which is not NULL
    return str;
}
```