# Is compound if checking for null and then other condition in C++ always safe?

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-precedence

(this question is an exact copy of [Is compound if checking for null and then other condition in C always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776657/is-compound-if-checking-for-null-and-then-value-always-safe) but about **C++**, not C. It was pointed out that the question should be more specific).

I have been using the following type of `if` condition for a lot of time.

```
char* ptr = ...;
if (ptr != NULL && ptr[0] != '\0') // <=== is this always safe?
{ /* ... */ }
```

It relies on `ptr != NULL` being checked before `ptr[0] !='\0'`.

Is it safe under all standards, compilers, architectures? Or is there a possibility that `ptr[0] != '\0'` will be checked before `ptr != NULL`?

Comment: Thanks for re-posting. That was the correct thing to do (separate languages) but this question has already been asked many times in the past. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I've seen the close suggestions and it's true, that's the same question. It's OK if it gets closed. I won't delete it though, it's yet another way to rephrase the same problem, so it'll attract more google hits.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe in this case. [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) means that the RHS of the `&&` operator will only be evaluated if the first is true.

C++ allows to override `bool operator &&` for user defined types. Using an overriden `&&` does not follow short-circuit evaluation, so the safety is lost. It is rarely a good idea to overload this operator.

Here's an example showing the behaviour of an overloaded `&&` operator:

```
struct Foo {};

bool operator && (const Foo&, const Foo&) { return true; }

#include <iostream>

Foo make_foo()
{
  std::cout << "making foo\n";
  return Foo();
}

int main()
{
  make_foo() && make_foo(); // evaluates both expressions
}
```

Comment: `s/built-in types/user-defined types/`?

Comment: @FredOverflow Thanks. I can't believe I got three up-votes with that glaring mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It is safe as long as operator `&&` is not overloaded

C++ standard draft says (N3337 - 5.14 Logical AND operator):

> The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to type bool (Clause 4).
>   The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

Comment: I didn't find the relevant part about the overloading form the standard yet. I'll add it when I find it.